# ag grid not loading in Internet Explorer with polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, ag-grid, polyfills

We have created custom element for ag-grid with polymer 2.0. The component is loaded  as expected in chrome ,how ever it is not loaded in IE. If any one have a solution for this problem,please let us know.Please find below the code that i have tried:

ag-grid.html
Ag-grid component html file

```
   <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/ag-grid-polymer/ag-grid-polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="./parent-child-renderer.html">
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="./ag-grid.css">-->
    <dom-module id="simple-grid-example">
        <template id="template">

            <head>
                <script src="/bower_components/ag-grid/dist/ag-grid.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/ag-grid/ag-grid.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-fresh.css">

            </head>

            <div class="toolbar">
                <label id="search">Search:</label><input type="text" id="quickFilter"> <button id="addrow">Add Row</button><br>
            </div>
            <ag-grid-polymer id="myGrid" style="height: 350px; width: 1000px;" class="ag-fresh ag-basic" row-height="22" on-grid-ready="[[onGridReady]]"></ag-grid-polymer>

        </template>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./ag-grid.js">

        </script>
    </dom-module>
```

ag-grid.css
Style sheet for the custom element simple-grid-example.this will override the basic ag-grid style.

```
 .ag-paging-page-summary-panel {
                    float: left!important;
                }

                .ag-fresh .ag-header {
                    color: #fff !important;
                    background: #00559b!important;
                }

                .ag-fresh .ag-menu-option-active {
                    background-color: #e3f6ff!important;
                }

                .ag-fresh .ag-menu {
                    background-color: #fff!important;
                    font-size: 13px!important;
                    box-shadow: 0px 4px 9px 1px #cecece!important;
                }

                .ag-fresh .ag-row-odd {
                    background-color: #e3f6ff!important;
                }

                .ag-fresh {
                    color: #2d2d2d!important;
                }

                .ag-fresh .ag-paging-button {
                    margin-left: 4px!important;
                    margin-right: 4px!important;
                    cursor: pointer!important;
                    background: #fff!important;
                    border: solid 1px #cecece!important;
                }

                .ag-fresh .ag-paging-button:hover {
                    background: #0076BE!important;
                    border: solid 1px #cecece!important;
                    color: #fff!important
                }

                span.ag-paging-page-summary-panel {
                    float: right!important;
                }

                .ag-fresh .ag-ltr .ag-cell-no-focus {
                    border-right: 0!important;
                }

                .ag-fresh .ag-header-icon {
                    color: #fff!important;;
                    stroke: none!important;;
                    fill: #fff!important;;
                }

                .toolbar {
                    background: #00559b;
                    color: white;
                    width: 1000px;
                    height: 30px;
                    padding-top: 10px;
                }

                #addrow {
                    margin-left: 32px;
                }

                #search {
                    padding-left: 10px
                }
```

ag-grid.js

```
class SimpleGridExample extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() {
        return "simple-grid-example";
    }
    static get properties() {
        return {
            columnDefs: {
                type: Object
            },
            rowData: {
                type: Object
            },
            filter: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: true
            },
            order: {
                type: Array,
                value: ['desc', 'asc', null]
            },
            gridOptions: {
                type: Object
            },
            selectedRows: {
                type: Array
            },
            masterColumnDefs: {
                type: Array
            },
            detailColumnDefs: {
                type: Array
            }
        }
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.columnDefs = [
            { headerName: "Make", field: "make", width: 238, cellRenderer: 'group', cellRendererParams: { suppressCount: true } },
            { headerName: "Model", field: "model", width: 238 },
            { headerName: "Price", field: "price", width: 237 },
            { headerName: "Edit/Delete", field: "price", width: 187, cellRendererFramework: 'child-cell-renderer' },
            { headerName: "Athlete", field: "athlete", width: 100, checkboxSelection: true, headerCheckboxSelection: true, headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true }
        ];
        this.rowData = [
            { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
            { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
            { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000 },
            { make: "TrailBlazer", model: "2000 ", price: 235465 },
            { make: "Trans Sport", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },
            { make: "Tredia", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },
            { make: "Tribute", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },
            { make: "Trooper", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },
            { make: "Tundra", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },
            { make: "Turbo", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },
            { make: "Turismo", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },
            { make: "Vanagon", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },
            { make: "Vandura", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },
            { make: "Vanquish", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },
            { make: "Vantage", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },
            { make: "VehiCROSS", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },
            { make: "Venture", model: " 2000", price: 235465 },

        ];
        this.gridOptions = {
            columnDefs: this.columnDefs,
            rowData: this.rowData,
            rowSelection: 'multiple',
            enableFilter: 'true',
            accentedSort: this.filter,
            sortingOrder: this.order,
            enableSorting: this.filter,
            groupSelectsChildren: 'true',
            pagination: true,
            paginationPageSize: 10,
            defaultColDef: {
                editable: true
            },

        }
        this.detailColumnDefs = [
            { headerName: 'Call ID', field: 'callId', cellClass: 'call-record-cell' },
            { headerName: 'Direction', field: 'direction', cellClass: 'call-record-cell' },
            { headerName: 'Number', field: 'number', cellClass: 'call-record-cell' },
            { headerName: 'Duration', field: 'duration', cellClass: 'call-record-cell' },
            { headerName: 'Switch', field: 'switchCode', cellClass: 'call-record-cell' }
        ];
    }
    ready() {
        super.ready();
        this.$.myGrid.gridOptions = this.gridOptions;
        // this.addEventListener('click', e => this.onSelectionChanged(e));

        this.$.addrow.addEventListener('click', e => { this.onAddRow(e) });
        // this.$.myGrid.addEventListener('click', e => { this.onSelectionChanged(e) });
        this.$.quickFilter.addEventListener('keyup', e => { this.filtergrid(e) });


    }
    onAddRow(e) {

        let newItem = this.createNewRowData();
        var res = this.gridOptions.api.updateRowData({ add: newItem });
        this.printResult(res);
    }
    printResult(res) {
        console.log('---------------------------------------')
        if (res.add) {
            res.add.forEach(function (rowNode) {
                console.log('Added Row Node', rowNode);
            });
        }
        if (res.remove) {
            res.remove.forEach(function (rowNode) {
                console.log('Removed Row Node', rowNode);
            });
        }
        if (res.update) {
            res.update.forEach(function (rowNode) {
                console.log('Updated Row Node', rowNode);
            });
        }
    }
    createNewRowData() {

        var newData = [{
            make: "Toyota " + newCount,
            model: "Celica " + newCount,
            price: 35000 + (newCount * 17),
            zombies: 'Headless',
            style: 'Little',
            clothes: 'Airbag'
        }];
        newCount++;
        return newData;
    }

    onGridReady(params) {
        console.log("Grid is now ready");

    }
    // onSelectionChanged(params) {
    //     console.log(event);
    //     this.selectedRows = this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
    //     console.log(this.selectedRows);
    // }
    filtergrid(event) {
        this.gridOptions.api.setQuickFilter(event.target.value);
    }


}
customElements.define(SimpleGridExample.is, SimpleGridExample);
var newCount = 1;
```

parent-child-renderer

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<dom-module id="child-cell-renderer">
    <template>
        <style>
            #dialog{
                width: 350;
                height:250px;
            }
             .text {
                    padding-left: 25px;
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin-right: 10px;
                    width: 150px;

                }
                label {
                    width: 75px;
                    clear: left;
                    padding-right: 10px;
                    float: left
                }
        </style>
        <span><button style="height: 20px" on-click="invokeParentMethod" id="edit">Edit</button><button style="height: 20px" on-click="invokeParentMethod">Delete</button></span>
        <paper-dialog id="dialog">
            <label>Make:</label><input type="text" class="text" value=[[data.make]]><br>
            <label>Model:</label><input type="text" class="text" value=[[data.model]]><br>
            <label>Price:</label><input type="text" class="text" value=[[data.price]]><br>
            <br>
            <button>Save</button><br>
            <button on-click="updateGrid" dialog-dismiss>Cancel</button><br>
        </paper-dialog>
    </template>

    <script>
        class ParentChildCellRenderer extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() {
                return 'child-cell-renderer'
            }
            static get properties(){
                return{
                    data:{
                    type:Array
                    }
                }
            }
            agInit(params) {
                this.params = params;
            }

            invokeParentMethod() {
                this.params.context.componentParent.methodFromParent(`Row: ${this.params.node.rowIndex}, Col: ${this.params.colDef.headerName}`)
                //  var selectedRows = this.params.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows();
                console.log(this.params.data.make);
                this.data=this.params.data;

            }
            toggleDialog(e) {
                this.$.dialog.toggle();
            }
            updateGrid(){

            }
            ready() {
                super.ready();
                this.$.edit.addEventListener('click', e => { this.toggleDialog(e) });

            }
        }

        customElements.define(ParentChildCellRenderer.is, ParentChildCellRenderer);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Could you please share the code you have tried so far!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ag grid not loading in IE with polymer 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46219280/ag-grid-not-loading-in-ie-with-polymer-2-0)

Comment: question is updated with the code used

Comment: That above link is no longer found. Does anyone know the answer to this?